# Convert SQL statement to Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named Outweigh which has around 50 fields. I need to create a Linq query which is like this SQL query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product, 
   Medication, 
   SUM(NettWeight) as NettWt, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CustCode) as Customer, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT DktNo)as DktNo
FROM outweigh
GROUP BY Product, Medication
ORDER BY Product, Medication
```

The result is below:

[image]

I have written some code as below which is not very efficient.

```
lstOutWeigh = dbContext.Outweighs
                       .Where(o => o.DateOut >= StartDate && o.DateOut <= EndDate)
                       .ToList();

  var k = from t in lstOutWeigh select new {t.Product,t.Medication,t.NettWeight};
  var l  = from t in k
           group t by new { t.Product, t.Medication } into g
           select new someclass
           {
               prod =g.Key.Product,
               med = g.Key.Medication,
               tonnes = (double) g.Sum(x => x.NettWeight),
               count = g.Count()
           };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://sqltolinq.com/

Comment: What is lstOutWeigh and how is it populated? You may be inadvertantly pulling back all records from the database and using linq to objects instead of linq to entities.

Comment: "not very efficient" seems to be the key part of your question, but that doesn't supply enough detail for us to actually help.  If your Linq statement works, but you're asking for performance help, please be clearer.

Comment: Do you need the top level distinct in your SQL? What is the schema of the of this table, what is the interface of the model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var t = (from  p in Context.outweigh
              group p by new {p.Product,p.Medication}  into g
              select new {Product= t.Product,Medication=t.Medication, NettWt = g.Sum(x => x.NettWeight),Customer=g.Count())
             .Distinct().orderby(new {p.Product, p.Medication});
```

Comment: I think the outer distinct is spurious and you have omitted the distincts on the counts which may be relevant. If we are grouping no two rows in the result set can have the same group.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned, http://sqltolinq.com/ works well.

http://www.linqpad.net/ is also another great tool (that I/we personally use where I work) that can help you convert between those types of statements - even using Lambda expressions if you'd like - which in my opinion is one of the easiest ways to query using LINQ.

Comment: lots of things work well but, since a question that asks for a tool recommendation would be off topic, an answer that offers one must be too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
db.Outweighs.GroupBy(ow => new { ow.Product, ow.Medication })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => new
        {
            g.Key.Product,
            g.Key.Medication,
            NettWt = g.Sum(ow => ow.NettWeight),
            Customer = g.Select(ow => ow.CustCode).Distinct().Count(),
            DktNo = g.Select(ow => ow.DktNo).Distinct().Count()
        })
```

is equivalent to the SQL you present in the question. However, the Linq-To-Sql you present doesen't match up.